# Facebook Marketing API Development Mode

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I just added Marketing API to my Facebook app to retrieve leads from a leadgen form. In the Marketing API Settings section it says: Ads API Access Level: development and in details it says App doesn't have Ads Management Standard Access. However, on permissions section it says that I already have standard access to Ads Management Standard. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to request advanced access for Ads Management Standard Access and submit your Facebook app for review.

Once approved, your Ads API Access Level should automatically change to "standard".

Comment: does the Ads API Access level take a while to change to standard? I got Advanced Access approved for ads_management but i still see my Ads API Access Level at development and below that it still says: App unappoved for "Ads Management Standard Access". Is there anything else needed to increase this API access?

Comment: @user12345, you need advanced access for the permission named "Ads Management Standard Access"

Comment: many thanks I misunderstood. All I'm trying to achieve is to connect my app to our Ad account to retrieve comments on our ads but i keep getting permissions errors with my code, despite being able to do so in the FB QPI explorer, so I assume my app does not have the right permissions. I've added it to the ad Account in business manager - do you know if anything else is required? I have ads_management advanced access permission too now

Comment: @user12345, it sounds like you're missing a permission which is a bit different from this question. In the API explorer, you can test adding extra permissions that aren't assigned to your ad account so thats probably why its only working from there. I'd recommend finding out which one you're missing for the comments API and request that.